# Read data from image in PDF

Tags: java, itext, pdf-parsing

I am using **iText java TextExtraction** to read text from PDF file. I use below code and it **works fine for PDF in English** Now I have PDF containing data as image. I want to read data from that image

```
public class pdfreader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, TransformerException {
        String SRC = "";
        String DEST = "";

        for (String s : args) {
            SRC = args[0];
            DEST = args[1];
        }
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new pdfreader().readText(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void readText(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException, TransformerException {
         try {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(src);
                PdfReaderContentParser PdfParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(
                        pdfReader);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                        dest));
                TextExtractionStrategy textStrategy;
                for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                    textStrategy = PdfParser.processContent(i,
                            new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                    out.println(textStrategy.getResultantText());
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                pdfReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an OCR workflow with iText. As Amedee already hinted, this is something we have tried at iText, with very promising results.

The algorithm (high level):

1. Implement IEventListener to parse pages of your document
2. Look out for ImageRenderInfo events, they are fired when the PDF parser hits an image
3. You can call `getImage()` on the event and ultimately get a BufferedImage
4. Feed the BufferedImage to Tesseract
5. Apply the coordinate transform (tesseract does not use the same coordinate space as iText)
6. Now that you have the texf in the image, and the location, you can use iText to overlay text on your PDF. Or simply extract it.

Answer (score 1):

iText doesn't support OCR to extract text from images. Try to use [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) or something else.

Comment: Can I extract image from PDF using iText

Comment: Yes you can extract an image from a pdf with iText, and then feed that image to Tessaract, but that was not your question.

Comment: I was thinking to extract image first and then read data from image